# Xamarin form Progressbar method progressTo doesn't work on some Android Device

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, progress-bar

I tried to make a little app. I have a progressBar and a button. When i click to my button, it starts a countdown on my progressBar for 30 seconds. It works on all my emulators android phone except for that phones : 
- Samsung Galaxy j5 pro (Android 8.0) 
- HTC One M8 (Android 6.0)

On that devices, it just goes to 0 in less than 1 second.

i found this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/134407/progressbar-progressto-only-works-on-some-devices  But there is no answers

Here is my MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ProgressApp.MainPage">
   <StackLayout>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" HeightRequest="20" Progress="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Button Text="Start !"
                FontSize="20"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BackgroundColor="#00b484"
                TextColor="White"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                Clicked="OnCommencerClicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ProgressApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
         public MainPage()
         {
             InitializeComponent();

         }

         private void OnCommencerClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
         {
             try
             {
                 progressBar.ProgressTo(0, 30000, Easing.Linear);
             }
             catch (System.Exception exc)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
             }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best Way to make this is Using MVVM. In may case this code dosen't work